# How to control NFC permissions popup on some Android devices?

Tags: android, react-native, nfc

I am building an application based on React Native and using NFC. I have taken this library https://github.com/revtel/react-native-nfc-manager and all works well but on some android devices, I see this popup:

[image]

As far as I know, NFC permission is listed as a normal level (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#NFC) and shouldn't request any user access.

My question is: how I can control this popup? For example, I want to show it when I request NFC but not when I start my app. Now it appears without any logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFC permission has normal protection level so it doesn't require user approval. However it can be implemented differently by vendors (this one looks like from xiaomi). There is no way to control it.